# I am writing a C# Console App that Allows the user to set the inital temperature, and adjust it, but I am not getting the desired output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console

Here is my source code:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Set initial Temperature");
                int set_temperature = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                ThermostatView.ControlTemperature(set_temperature);
                Console.WriteLine("Continue? ");
                string Continue = Console.ReadLine();
                if (Continue == "no".ToUpper())
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }


    class Thermostat 
    {

        int defaultTemp { get; set; } 
        int decrease { get; set; }
        int increase { get; set; }


        public Thermostat()
        { }
        public Thermostat(int DefaultTemp) 
        {
            defaultTemp = DefaultTemp;
            CurrentTemperature(defaultTemp);


        }

        public void CurrentTemperature(int defaultTemp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current Temperature: {0}", defaultTemp);
        }

        public void ControlThermostat()
        {

            int Choice;
            Console.WriteLine("Increase(1) or Decrease(2) Temperature");
            Choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            ValidateControl(Choice);


        }

        public void ValidateControl(int choice) 
        {


                if (choice == 2)
                {
                    if(defaultTemp==0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Temperature at Minimum Setting!");

                    }
                    else {
                            Console.WriteLine("Decrease by: ");
                            decrease = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                            DecreaseTemperature(decrease);
                         }
                }
                if (choice == 1)
                {
                    if(defaultTemp == 100) 
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Temperature at Maximum Setting!");

                        }
                    else
                        {
                             Console.WriteLine("Increase by: ");
                             increase = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                             IncreaseTemperature(increase);
                        }

                }
         }

        public void IncreaseTemperature(int increaseTemp) 
        {

            defaultTemp =+ increaseTemp;
            CurrentTemperature(defaultTemp);
        }

        public void DecreaseTemperature(int decreaseTemp)
        {
            defaultTemp =- decreaseTemp;
            CurrentTemperature(defaultTemp);

        }


    }

    class ThermostatView 
    {



        public static void ControlTemperature(int Temperature) 
        {
            Thermostat thermostat = new Thermostat(Temperature);
            thermostat.ControlThermostat();
        }

    }


}
```

Here is my Output:

Console Window:

Set initial Temperature
72(User Input)

Current Temperature: 72

Increase(1) or Decrease(2) Temperature

2(User Input)

Decrease by:
40(User Input)

Current Temperature: -40

How Do I get the initial temperature, which was 72 in this case to be changed, instead of the value 0 being increased or decreased?

Answer (score 2):

Your function to decrease the temperature is

```
    defaultTemp =- decreaseTemp;
```

That is the wrong operator and it should be

```
    defaultTemp -= decreaseTemp;
```

You've made the same mistake with the =+ that should be +=